# Can you uniquely identify a BLE MAC address in Android 5.0?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-5.0-lollipop, spoofing

In Android 5.0, BLE doesn't use static MAC addresses anymore, but the MACs change after intervals, using a method called IRK and public key cryptography.

Is it possible to uniquely identify an Android phone in a way that can not be spoofed by the user of that phone, or has that become completely impossible now unless the other side co-operates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. That's the whole idea of using IRKs: **only** bonded devices can identify it after the address changes. For those who do not possess the IRK (because they have not bonded), it would always appear as a completely new device (hence the privacy).

Comment: How are bonded keys stored? Suppose two device have bonded, is it easy for the Android user to clear the local keys, and use different one next time?

Comment: Those are details of implementation of the host stack. The user doesn't have access to this kind of stuff.

Comment: But do you happen to know how most Android phones deal with this? Because my whole plan will fail if they are very easy to change.

Comment: They cannot be changed surely. Otherwise bonds would get lost.

Answer (score 0):

The private address is generated using the devices IRK exchanged during the previous pairing/bonding procedure. So if they have not bonded, you can't get irk.