# My BLE Peripheral service not discovered on android with Samsung Galaxy Note 3

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm creating a BLE peripheral on my Samsung Galaxy Note3 (API=21). The code seems to be reasonable and the device is discovered (slowly) but services can't be discovered (testing with LightBlue app on my mac) - it's waiting and waiting and no services are shown.

Is this a hardware issue or am i doing something wrong?

Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "BleTest";
    public static final String START_PERIPHERAL_GATT_SERVER = "startPeripheralGattServer()";
    public static final String FAILED_TO_CREATE_GATT_SERVER = "Failed to create Gatt server";
    public static final String START_ADVERTISING = "startAdvertising()";

    private BluetoothGattServer mGattServer;

    private byte response = 0x55;

    public void startPeripheralGattServer() {
        Log.d(TAG, START_PERIPHERAL_GATT_SERVER);
        Toast.makeText(this, "startPeripheralGattServer()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) this.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);

        BluetoothAdapter  bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        boolean isMultipleAdvertisementSupported = bluetoothAdapter.isMultipleAdvertisementSupported();
        boolean isOffloadedFilteringSupported = bluetoothAdapter.isOffloadedFilteringSupported();
        boolean isOffloadedScanBatchingSupported = bluetoothAdapter.isOffloadedScanBatchingSupported();

        Log.d(TAG, "Hardware support:"
                + " isMultipleAdvertisementSupported=" + isMultipleAdvertisementSupported
                + " isOffloadedFilteringSupported=" + isOffloadedFilteringSupported
                + " isOffloadedScanBatchingSupported=" + isOffloadedScanBatchingSupported);

        try {
            mGattServer = bluetoothManager.openGattServer(getApplicationContext(), new BluetoothGattServerCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCharacteristicReadRequest(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId,
                                                        int offset, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

                    if (mGattServer != null) {
                        mGattServer.sendResponse(device, requestId, BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS, offset, new byte[]{ response++ });
                        Log.d(TAG, "Sent response");
                    }
                }
            });


            UUID serviceUUID = UUID.fromString("6855f2ce-8dc6-4228-8bec-531167e0266b");
            UUID characteristicUUID = UUID.fromString("09de1235-6594-4a2b-8d88-ad5eb8cc57c6");
            UUID descriptorUUID = UUID.fromString("c3a29c57-7a4b-492c-b7c4-7d807f9639d2");

            Log.d(TAG, "Service = " + serviceUUID);
            Log.d(TAG, "characteristic = " + characteristicUUID);
            Log.d(TAG, "descriptor = " + descriptorUUID);

            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(
                    characteristicUUID, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ);
            characteristic.setValue(77, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0);

            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = new BluetoothGattDescriptor(descriptorUUID,
                    BluetoothGattDescriptor.PERMISSION_READ);

            characteristic.addDescriptor(descriptor);

            BluetoothGattService service = new BluetoothGattService(serviceUUID, BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);
            service.addCharacteristic(characteristic);

            mGattServer.addService(service);

            // advertise
            BluetoothLeAdvertiser advertiser =  bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();
            if (advertiser != null) {
                startAdvertising(serviceUUID, advertiser);
            }

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, FAILED_TO_CREATE_GATT_SERVER, t);
            Toast.makeText(this, FAILED_TO_CREATE_GATT_SERVER, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
    }

    private void startAdvertising(UUID serviceUUID, BluetoothLeAdvertiser advertiser) {
        Log.d(TAG, "startAdvertising()");
        Toast.makeText(this, START_ADVERTISING, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        AdvertiseSettings settings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
                .setConnectable(true)
                .setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                .build();

        AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
                .setIncludeDeviceName(true)
                .addServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(serviceUUID))
                .setIncludeTxPowerLevel(true)
                .build();

        advertiser.startAdvertising(settings, data, new AdvertiseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
                super.onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
                super.onStartFailure(errorCode);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mGattServer != null)
            mGattServer.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        Toast.makeText(this, "API = " + currentapiVersion, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (currentapiVersion >= 21)
            startPeripheralGattServer();
        else
            Log.d(TAG, "BLE not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Log:

```
05-21 11:13:33.741  26925-26925/? E/Zygote﹕ MountEmulatedStorage()
05-21 11:13:33.741  26925-26925/? E/Zygote﹕ v2
05-21 11:13:33.741  26925-26925/? I/libpersona﹕ KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10012
05-21 11:13:33.741  26925-26925/? I/libpersona﹕ KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
05-21 11:13:33.751  26925-26925/? I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SM-N9005_4.4.2 ver=40
05-21 11:13:33.751  26925-26925/? I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-N9005_5.0_0009
05-21 11:13:33.751  26925-26925/? E/SELinux﹕ [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
05-21 11:13:33.751  26925-26925/? I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
05-21 11:13:33.791  26925-26925/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider﹕ TimaSignature is unavailable
05-21 11:13:33.791  26925-26925/? D/ActivityThread﹕ Added TimaKeyStore provider
05-21 11:13:33.831  26925-26925/project.name.myapplication D/ResourcesManager﹕ creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/project.name.myapplication-1/base.apk
05-21 11:13:33.981  26925-26925/project.name.myapplication D/BleTest﹕ startPeripheralGattServer()
05-21 11:13:33.991  26925-26925/project.name.myapplication D/BleTest﹕ Hardware support: isMultipleAdvertisementSupported=false isOffloadedFilteringSupported=true isOffloadedScanBatchingSupported=false
05-21 11:13:33.991  26925-26925/project.name.myapplication D/BluetoothGattServer﹕ registerCallback()
05-21 11:13:34.001  26925-26925/project.name.myapplication D/BluetoothGattServer﹕ registerCallback() - UUID=df2bf3e0-f7b7-4be1-9c73-338eec1eeda7
05-21 11:13:34.001  26925-26934/project.name.myapplication D/BluetoothGattServer﹕ onServerRegistered() - status=0 serverIf=6
05-21 11:13:34.001  26925-26925/project.name.myapplication D/BleTest﹕ Service = 6855f2ce-8dc6-4228-8bec-531167e0266b
05-21 11:13:34.001  26925-26925/project.name.myapplication D/BleTest﹕ characteristic = 09de1235-6594-4a2b-8d88-ad5eb8cc57c6
05-21 11:13:34.001  26925-26925/project.name.myapplication D/BleTest﹕ descriptor = c3a29c57-7a4b-492c-b7c4-7d807f9639d2
05-21 11:13:34.001  26925-26925/project.name.myapplication D/BluetoothGattServer﹕ addService() - service: 6855f2ce-8dc6-4228-8bec-531167e0266b
05-21 11:13:34.011  26925-26936/project.name.myapplication D/BluetoothGattServer﹕ onServiceAdded() - service=6855f2ce-8dc6-4228-8bec-531167e0266bstatus=0
05-21 11:13:34.011  26925-26925/project.name.myapplication E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ bluetooth le advertising not supported
05-21 11:13:34.011  26925-26925/project.name.myapplication D/Activity﹕ performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
05-21 11:13:34.011  26925-26925/project.name.myapplication D/Activity﹕ performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
05-21 11:13:34.031  26925-26971/project.name.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
05-21 11:13:34.071  26925-26971/project.name.myapplication I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1_RB1.05.00.00.002.025_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.01.03
    Build Date: 11/19/14 Wed
    Local Branch: mybranch5813579
    Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1_rb1.11
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1_RB1.05.00.00.002.025 + 30e7589 +  NOTHING
05-21 11:13:34.071  26925-26971/project.name.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-21 11:13:34.101  26925-26971/project.name.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ HWUI protection enabled for context ,  &this =0xafa22088 ,&mEglDisplay = 1 , &mEglConfig = 8
05-21 11:13:34.101  26925-26971/project.name.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-21 11:13:34.241  26925-26925/project.name.myapplication I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@248edbf4 time:3431520
05-21 11:13:38.581  26925-26925/project.name.myapplication I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@248edbf4 time:3435866
05-21 11:13:49.811  26925-26932/project.name.myapplication I/art﹕ Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
```

PS. Actually i'm not sure that it's my device discovered - it's found with title "Unknown".

Comment: Is is recognizable by mac address?

Comment: how can i do it using mac address? i'm not sure it's possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602672/android-5-static-bluetooth-mac-address-for-ble-advertising and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376075/can-you-uniquely-identify-a-ble-mac-address-in-android-5-0

Comment: Hmm.. Your log says: "bluetooth le advertising not supported", so your Note3 might not be able to do it..

Comment: afaik advertising is required for normal ble workflow. How can ble peripheral be discovered if not using advertising? Does it mean it will not discovered and consequently will not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log says: "bluetooth le advertising not supported".

Although you are right that a device with Bluetooth V4.0 and API 21 should support peripheral mode (be able to advertise), it seems this is not the case for the Samsung Galaxy Note 3.

Have a look at the [Samsung forum](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/ble-peripheral-mode/201/280106?boardName=SDK&startId=zzzzz~&searchSubId=0000000007) where this issue is reported.

Comment: it seems you're right. any confirmations from anyone?

Comment: heh, that's my post that you lined linked! I've been looking for a solution for some time now. The Note 3 doesn't seem to support it and I've confirmed this with multiple applications. I'm hoping that, similar to the Nexus 5, Android is just missing a flag which can be turned on with a custom ROM.

Answer (score 2):

According to this link https://newcircle.com/s/post/1697/android_lollipop_bluetooth_andevcon, the new features of Android 5 BLE API is in Hardware Abstraction Layer or HAL - meaning it depends on the bluetooth chipset capability and on whether the manufacturer enables it in their devices when they updated to Android 5. So these 3 functions must be run first in order to find out if these features are supported by your hardware.

```
bluetoothAdapter.isMultipleAdvertisementSupported();

bluetoothAdapter.isOffloadedFilteringSupported();

bluetoothAdapter.isOffloadedScanBatchingSupported();
```

Comment: if you see my source code in the question you can find i check for it. the question is if it's the reason or not. thanks anyway

Comment: Yes, you just checked for them and log them in the logcat, but in your code  you did not use them to notify that your hardware does not support them. :-)